# NSSegmentedControl image behavior different on snow leopard and lion

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, button, icons

Why do images placed in NSSegmentedControls on snow leopard appear in a different position from that of Lion?

Lion:
[image]

Snow Leopard:[image]

They are textured square buttons with the EXACT same png files.

EDIT: I need a work around for this.  The images are 19x19 (recommended by the HIG)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be subclassing NSSegmentedCell and hooking into the method that draws the images.  It's a rather manual process, but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Lion introduced some changes in the Aqua framework and the UI and this is part of it.

Comment: Err, there is no solution beside implementing NSSegmentedControl by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a duplicate with a couple empty pixels to the top of your image files and do a version check in code?